What can cause the missing of material in an area of the bed?
I have a Sovol SV-04 printer and here what happened when I ran a "duplicate mode" job:

As you can see the left extruder did not complete the first layers. I can't understand what is the problem.

it's hard to believe it was due to a problem in the feeder, since also the skirt has the same issue and - more important - this is repeatable

if it was due to non-planar plate (my first thought) I wonder where the extruded material went! There was no debris on the extruder or around the bed


Anyway, after the first layers even the left printing was ok.
What should I check in my printer?

That is odd. That the outlines put down 1st work but the later fill does not. Question: If you printed this 1st layer several times, would it look the same each time? If not, I'd look for momentary problems like bad wires to the hot end heater or cracked parts with respect to the filament stepping motor.

@st2000, in the next days I have to print it again and I'll pay more attention. I'm sure the issue is repeatable, but I can't say it looks exactly the same every time.

How flat is your bed ?

@st2000, yes, the printings are consistent

@Criggie, how could I answer to your question? Anyway, even if that area is uneven, why I don't find the material not deposited?

"
@st2000, yes, the printings are consistent". That is confusing. I might still suggest momentary problems. Octoprint is a great way to see the hot end temperature vs time during a print. However, I don't know if it works w/a 2 head printer. Also, if this has not always been a problem, you might try an older (proven) G-Code file and check if it still prints as well as it did before.

"How flat is your bed ?". Octoprint combined with a bed level sensor can produce 3D views of your bed height. Again, I don't know how well or even if this will work w/a 2 head FDM printer.
